# How do I render from one render target to another?

Tags: c++, directx9, rendertargets

I have two render targets:

1. a **fake backbuffer**; a special render target where I do all my rendering.
2. a **light render target**; where I render my light fx.

I'm sure I'm rendering correctly on both.

The problem arises when I overlay the **light render target** onto the **fake
backbuffer** by drawing a quad covering it:

```
DxEngine.DrawSprite(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    (float)DxEngine.GetWidth(), (float)DxEngine.GetHeight(),
    0xFFFFFFFF, LightSurface->GetTexture());
```

Regardless of what's in the light target, nothing is rendered onto the other target. I tried clearing the light target with full-white or full-black, but still get nothing.

---

Fake backbuffer created with

```
Direct3dDev->CreateTexture(Width, Height, 1, D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET,
    D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &Texture, nullptr);
```

Light render target created with

```
Direct3dDev->CreateTexture(Width, Height, 1, D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET,
    D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &Texture, nullptr);
```

I also tried to create both with `D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8`, again without difference.
Both targets have the same width and height.

Only the fixed pipeline is used

DirectX setup for rendering :

```
Direct3dDev->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MINFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR );
Direct3dDev->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MAGFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR );
Direct3dDev->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MIPFILTER, D3DTEXF_NONE );
Direct3dDev->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_ADDRESSU, D3DTADDRESS_WRAP );
Direct3dDev->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_ADDRESSV, D3DTADDRESS_WRAP );
Direct3dDev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_CULLMODE, D3DCULL_NONE);
Direct3dDev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, false);
Direct3dDev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, D3DZB_TRUE);
Direct3dDev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZWRITEENABLE,D3DZB_TRUE);
Direct3dDev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZFUNC,D3DCMP_LESSEQUAL);

Direct3dDev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE,  true );
Direct3dDev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHAREF, 0x00000000ul);
Direct3dDev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHATESTENABLE, true);
Direct3dDev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHAFUNC,D3DCMP_GREATER);
Direct3dDev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND,  D3DBLEND_SRCALPHA );
Direct3dDev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_DESTBLEND, D3DBLEND_INVSRCALPHA );

Direct3dDev->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
Direct3dDev->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG2, D3DTA_DIFFUSE);
Direct3dDev->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_MODULATE);
Direct3dDev->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
Direct3dDev->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG2, D3DTA_DIFFUSE);
Direct3dDev->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_MODULATE);

Direct3dDev->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_RESULTARG, D3DTA_CURRENT);

Direct3dDev->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_TEXCOORDINDEX, D3DTSS_TCI_PASSTHRU);

//ensure the first stage is not used for now
Direct3dDev->SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_DISABLE);
```

How can I do this right?

Comment: Should i add some more details to attract an answer??

Comment: Yes, specifically how you set up your render targets, and how you set them to be rendered to. Are you trying to create a deferred renderer and want to write to multiple render targets at the same time MRT (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb147221(v=vs.85).aspx )

Comment: Ok, i'll add that, and no i don't think we could call what i'm doing deferred rendering, i just want to write to a single target at a time, btw i'm only rendering quads, no real 3d here.

Comment: What's this: `DxEngine.DrawSprite`?

Comment: You have the depth tests enabled so it might be that all your pixels are discarded by that. Or maybe a problem with alpha. This is the kind of issue that can be easily solved using PIX / Visual Studio Graphics Debugger. Learn how to use it, you won't regret it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the culprit, it was a really stupid typo error in my code, the light surface was not the same size as the backbuffer (width and height reversed)....

By the way i was able to pinpoint the problem really fast with PIX, if that can help someone.

Comment: Can you then mark your answer as correct answer?